# Пройти по всем ключам массива и сохранить значения в переменную в виде строки. Как лучше сделать?

Tags: php

Есть массив вида JSON {name: value, name: value, name: value}. Нужно пройти по всем ключам массива и сохранить значения в переменную в виде строки. Как лучше сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потратить пару секунд на клик в документацию мышкой совсем лень, да?

```
print join("",array_keys(json_decode($json,true)));
```

Comment: пытался через foreach сделать - нужно склеить в строку число, месяц и год. Так вот месяц где-то теряется. Ничего не могу понять...

Comment: Я тоже не могу понять: мы обсуждаем какую-то конкретную задачу и определённый набор данных, или говорим о птичках или погоде не Марсе? Какие такие месяцы, откуда там foreach...

Answer (score 1):

Хороший пример того, как задавая вопрос, человек старается всеми силами затруднить ответ на него.

Казалось бы - приведи пример реального запроса и пример желаемого результата. Что может быть проще? Но нет - мы лучше сочиним пример джейсона на коленке, а задачу опишем своими словами, путаясь в них сами и запутывая окружающих. Кто-то из этого объяснения понял, что нужны ключи. Мне же кажется, что склеивать нужно значения. Зачем было запутывать вопрос - для меня загадка.

В любом случае, склеивает массив в строку в РНР оператор `implode()`, также называемый `join()`. Больше ничего для решения этой задачи знать не надо. Разве что убедиться, что входящие данные соответствуют ожидаемым.